# Numerical integration in R : bad integrand behaviour error

Tags: r, integral, calculus, numerical-integration

This is my matrix

```
func=structure(c(-14.7690673280818, -14.5543581356252, -12.1406211639974, 
-10.7200919648493, -9.55507848352318, -9.20790894914246, -8.74647670464071, 
-8.26548763467919, -7.3962484443768, -6.94590909664862, -6.63903257406218, 
-6.40598087538929, -6.09621085755895, -5.88245015332806, -5.69615454359131, 
-5.4543516801245, -5.24485270997044, -5.05729667581875, -4.7660441793448, 
-4.39683466679171, -4.30668996362841, -4.0828498417172, -3.95528199743041, 
-3.81741171570944, -3.66175435590196, -3.56271256245504, -3.49609868983868, 
-3.37586125647396, -3.0034966287813, -2.90517151506904, -2.72993249556762, 
-2.66092057836039, -2.4408738658527, -2.36547969703899, -2.09546783234301, 
-1.95526398213212, -1.88470374007828, -1.72750243012653, -1.60575660667247, 
-1.43542615745848, -1.29362975715702, -1.18449733575892, -0.98947894198681, 
-0.853386354928181, -0.63296867063245, -0.527486151545778, -0.361277864998242, 
-0.257665212366851, -0.109270291541468, 0, 0.109270291541468, 
0.257665212366851, 0.361277864998242, 0.527486151545778, 0.63296867063245, 
0.853386354928181, 0.98947894198681, 1.18449733575892, 1.29362975715702, 
1.43542615745848, 1.60575660667247, 1.72750243012653, 1.88470374007828, 
1.95526398213212, 2.09546783234301, 2.36547969703899, 2.4408738658527, 
2.66092057836039, 2.72993249556762, 2.90517151506904, 3.0034966287813, 
3.37586125647396, 3.49609868983868, 3.56271256245504, 3.66175435590196, 
3.81741171570944, 3.95528199743041, 4.0828498417172, 4.30668996362841, 
4.39683466679171, 4.7660441793448, 5.05729667581875, 5.24485270997044, 
5.4543516801245, 5.69615454359131, 5.88245015332806, 6.09621085755895, 
6.40598087538929, 6.63903257406218, 6.94590909664862, 7.3962484443768, 
8.26548763467919, 8.74647670464071, 9.20790894914246, 9.55507848352318, 
10.7200919648493, 12.1406211639974, 14.5543581356252, 14.7690673280818, 
-13.7079821475458, -13.4498703618915, -11.67838231268, -10.4589486406842, 
-8.9432388382521, -8.58312548137122, -8.14102991846389, -7.71079209128989, 
-6.95240042017031, -6.66414427349685, -6.40033205538623, -6.13816822549321, 
-5.77208382991545, -5.49527630669887, -5.33154964830415, -5.12782641892739, 
-4.93206161073643, -4.72556232300793, -4.52080276980657, -4.1694078333758, 
-4.03956026669583, -3.90869860153294, -3.79104380757601, -3.69124767313376, 
-3.47159857371935, -3.3643163654408, -3.29467696235366, -3.16605701449292, 
-2.84435464789616, -2.71650210221017, -2.59690597248341, -2.52388797476942, 
-2.34094207608544, -2.20427426100811, -1.83879580218285, -1.72737794398069, 
-1.6454056454373, -1.5042411957216, -1.38609220687676, -1.2432788707001, 
-1.1225617148797, -1.01318771357089, -0.90038209504245, -0.773284479514442, 
-0.640368323748707, -0.555178375238413, -0.377358821158776, -0.230347860323025, 
-0.110436162251717, 0, 0.110436162251717, 0.230347860323025, 
0.377358821158776, 0.555178375238413, 0.640368323748707, 0.773284479514442, 
0.90038209504245, 1.01318771357089, 1.1225617148797, 1.2432788707001, 
1.38609220687676, 1.5042411957216, 1.6454056454373, 1.72737794398069, 
1.83879580218285, 2.20427426100811, 2.34094207608544, 2.52388797476942, 
2.59690597248341, 2.71650210221017, 2.84435464789616, 3.16605701449292, 
3.29467696235366, 3.3643163654408, 3.47159857371935, 3.69124767313376, 
3.79104380757601, 3.90869860153294, 4.03956026669583, 4.1694078333758, 
4.52080276980657, 4.72556232300793, 4.93206161073643, 5.12782641892739, 
5.33154964830415, 5.49527630669887, 5.77208382991545, 6.13816822549321, 
6.40033205538623, 6.66414427349685, 6.95240042017031, 7.71079209128989, 
8.14102991846389, 8.58312548137122, 8.9432388382521, 10.4589486406842, 
11.67838231268, 13.4498703618915, 13.7079821475458, -14.358609077878, 
-14.1271105147046, -11.9618138886078, -10.6190742201334, -9.31840132054895, 
-8.96622474353695, -8.51227248333579, -8.05091545299969, -7.22455526958365, 
-6.83691436333096, -6.54669635165921, -6.30238324376159, -5.97082920578328, 
-5.73268017960003, -5.55511488901834, -5.32804232266972, -5.12385612117062, 
-4.92897229198519, -4.67117775232928, -4.30885942992513, -4.20335651783943, 
-4.0154831357938, -3.89174994433905, -3.76860783727992, -3.58819663306074, 
-3.48596721027473, -3.41818297549918, -3.29470294456033, -2.94193593581688, 
-2.83218876260999, -2.67847401240583, -2.60791242809822, -2.40221737689215, 
-2.3031208003073, -1.99617971268181, -1.86711111167336, -1.79213635811389, 
-1.64113856670334, -1.52078410227216, -1.36109806339877, -1.22745572081485, 
-1.11822984936273, -0.955013720375685, -0.822400646878094, -0.635831069171161, 
-0.538198299721656, -0.367498441110635, -0.24709807532094, -0.109721283846771, 
0, 0.109721283846771, 0.24709807532094, 0.367498441110635, 0.538198299721656, 
0.635831069171161, 0.822400646878094, 0.955013720375685, 1.11822984936273, 
1.22745572081485, 1.36109806339877, 1.52078410227216, 1.64113856670334, 
1.79213635811389, 1.86711111167336, 1.99617971268181, 2.3031208003073, 
2.40221737689215, 2.60791242809822, 2.67847401240583, 2.83218876260999, 
2.94193593581688, 3.29470294456033, 3.41818297549918, 3.48596721027473, 
3.58819663306074, 3.76860783727992, 3.89174994433905, 4.0154831357938, 
4.20335651783943, 4.30885942992513, 4.67117775232928, 4.92897229198519, 
5.12385612117062, 5.32804232266972, 5.55511488901834, 5.73268017960003, 
5.97082920578328, 6.30238324376159, 6.54669635165921, 6.83691436333096, 
7.22455526958365, 8.05091545299969, 8.51227248333579, 8.96622474353695, 
9.31840132054895, 10.6190742201334, 11.9618138886078, 14.1271105147046, 
14.358609077878, -14.5672256639001, -14.3442603466748, -12.0526932005212, 
-10.6704167793823, -9.43869316924387, -9.08906143604798, -8.63130745231583, 
-8.15997238138419, -7.31181881941087, -6.89231124997616, -6.59362650222709, 
-6.3550370379524, -6.03455479085867, -5.80880119944129, -5.62679869904323, 
-5.39223941682433, -5.1853529853784, -4.99419352909143, -4.7193938866676, 
-4.35357309705323, -4.255876038818, -4.04972245780601, -3.92404029302206, 
-3.79341254883719, -3.62558255722496, -3.52497325621722, -3.4577838613747, 
-3.33595188997765, -2.97322433504632, -2.86928245642403, -2.70462793445213, 
-2.63485397290467, -2.42186464857093, -2.33481488889686, -2.04664318502277, 
-1.91191506158551, -1.8391839961936, -1.68503324864501, -1.56397162198931, 
-1.39887553095015, -1.26108886508264, -1.15191048988921, -0.972530768371285, 
-0.838149222100249, -0.634376246882453, -0.532753819606308, -0.364336815412981, 
-0.252468853112474, -0.109492065710681, 0, 0.109492065710681, 
0.252468853112474, 0.364336815412981, 0.532753819606308, 0.634376246882453, 
0.838149222100249, 0.972530768371285, 1.15191048988921, 1.26108886508264, 
1.39887553095015, 1.56397162198931, 1.68503324864501, 1.8391839961936, 
1.91191506158551, 2.04664318502277, 2.33481488889686, 2.42186464857093, 
2.63485397290467, 2.70462793445213, 2.86928245642403, 2.97322433504632, 
3.33595188997765, 3.4577838613747, 3.52497325621722, 3.62558255722496, 
3.79341254883719, 3.92404029302206, 4.04972245780601, 4.255876038818, 
4.35357309705323, 4.7193938866676, 4.99419352909143, 5.1853529853784, 
5.39223941682433, 5.62679869904323, 5.80880119944129, 6.03455479085867, 
6.3550370379524, 6.59362650222709, 6.89231124997616, 7.31181881941087, 
8.15997238138419, 8.63130745231583, 9.08906143604798, 9.43869316924387, 
10.6704167793823, 12.0526932005212, 14.3442603466748, 14.5672256639001, 
-13.6245844768687, -13.3630613956461, -11.6420519179073, -10.4384236674326, 
-8.89515033208928, -8.53401963497411, -8.0934438691888, -7.66719491633901, 
-6.91751548158816, -6.64199852086489, -6.38157100998465, -6.11711906602055, 
-5.74660855271358, -5.46484576488352, -5.30289294897202, -5.10216264876024, 
-4.90747729878566, -4.69948913603343, -4.50152763272595, -4.15153286112639, 
-4.01856478499323, -3.89501090892983, -3.77813524686729, -3.68133161034538, 
-3.45665297878437, -3.34872310204811, -3.27884590260074, -3.14956711773407, 
-2.83184663180451, -2.70167333082681, -2.5864505421683, -2.51311768021067, 
-2.33308777876224, -2.19160406439047, -1.81862225736669, -1.70946687980764, 
-1.6265976326061, -1.48669362532537, -1.36882733539455, -1.22817675030816, 
-1.10911635110033, -0.999723362435733, -0.89337938721453, -0.766988745723311, 
-0.640949911207503, -0.557354889428034, -0.37862272938278, -0.228200809764493, 
-0.110527795707098, 0, 0.110527795707098, 0.228200809764493, 
0.37862272938278, 0.557354889428034, 0.640949911207503, 0.766988745723311, 
0.89337938721453, 0.999723362435733, 1.10911635110033, 1.22817675030816, 
1.36882733539455, 1.48669362532537, 1.6265976326061, 1.70946687980764, 
1.81862225736669, 2.19160406439047, 2.33308777876224, 2.51311768021067, 
2.5864505421683, 2.70167333082681, 2.83184663180451, 3.14956711773407, 
3.27884590260074, 3.34872310204811, 3.45665297878437, 3.68133161034538, 
3.77813524686729, 3.89501090892983, 4.01856478499323, 4.15153286112639, 
4.50152763272595, 4.69948913603343, 4.90747729878566, 5.10216264876024, 
5.30289294897202, 5.46484576488352, 5.74660855271358, 6.11711906602055, 
6.38157100998465, 6.64199852086489, 6.91751548158816, 7.66719491633901, 
8.0934438691888, 8.53401963497411, 8.89515033208928, 10.4384236674326, 
11.6420519179073, 13.3630613956461, 13.6245844768687, -13.7513240158161, 
-13.4949850845108, -11.6972632618919, -10.4696154936035, -8.96823049188587, 
-8.60864584793023, -8.16576044465774, -7.73344959477095, -6.97053016408726, 
-6.67565344738059, -6.41008219291174, -6.14910749861269, -5.78532336166338, 
-5.51109109533802, -5.34644256890291, -5.14116391069274, -4.94483810678764, 
-4.73911258917317, -4.53082008138683, -4.17869747763421, -4.05047164341461, 
-3.91581211159757, -3.79775240187192, -3.6964010627146, -3.47936581711638, 
-3.37242020290272, -3.30290438286576, -3.17462683337767, -2.85085507867997, 
-2.72420863226898, -2.60233967200701, -2.52948530961352, -2.34502396371101, 
-2.21085897720345, -1.84928001732781, -1.73668634525457, -1.65518019199163, 
-1.51336068884896, -1.39506478104353, -1.25112746056258, -1.1295492863675, 
-1.02018515280999, -0.904021410598258, -0.776556379825624, -0.640066072057238, 
-0.554047238235075, -0.376701966557133, -0.231463685042374, -0.110388540236378, 
0, 0.110388540236378, 0.231463685042374, 0.376701966557133, 0.554047238235075, 
0.640066072057238, 0.776556379825624, 0.904021410598258, 1.02018515280999, 
1.1295492863675, 1.25112746056258, 1.39506478104353, 1.51336068884896, 
1.65518019199163, 1.73668634525457, 1.84928001732781, 2.21085897720345, 
2.34502396371101, 2.52948530961352, 2.60233967200701, 2.72420863226898, 
2.85085507867997, 3.17462683337767, 3.30290438286576, 3.37242020290272, 
3.47936581711638, 3.6964010627146, 3.79775240187192, 3.91581211159757, 
4.05047164341461, 4.17869747763421, 4.53082008138683, 4.73911258917317, 
4.94483810678764, 5.14116391069274, 5.34644256890291, 5.51109109533802, 
5.78532336166338, 6.14910749861269, 6.41008219291174, 6.67565344738059, 
6.97053016408726, 7.73344959477095, 8.16576044465774, 8.60864584793023, 
8.96823049188587, 10.4696154936035, 11.6972632618919, 13.4949850845108, 
13.7513240158161, -13.5038153563633, -13.2373523390222, -11.5894414578226, 
-10.4087012189772, -8.82551281645418, -8.46290889731311, -8.02453396711809, 
-7.60406134878737, -6.86699820314081, -6.6099290032563, -6.3544029256183, 
-6.08663753750477, -5.70971751250438, -5.42077894932731, -5.26139485499848, 
-5.06499864973269, -4.87187647554418, -4.66173225584577, -4.47361508632088, 
-4.12564790942336, -3.98816098787005, -3.87518960476143, -3.75944221250401, 
-3.66697204643782, -3.43501009186589, -3.32614231903036, -3.2559207639547, 
-3.12568790968636, -2.81373363068119, -2.68019961742924, -2.57130991397796, 
-2.49752109350884, -2.32171388099973, -2.17325620779303, -1.78940871644707, 
-1.68352966297731, -1.59936153416788, -1.46128278798956, -1.34382587758861, 
-1.20630719708568, -1.08964596607244, -0.980225481600834, -0.88323868593752, 
-0.757871821632761, -0.641792114656659, -0.560506724513046, -0.380453009333927, 
-0.225091641300559, -0.110660491161603, 0, 0.110660491161603, 
0.225091641300559, 0.380453009333927, 0.560506724513046, 0.641792114656659, 
0.757871821632761, 0.88323868593752, 0.980225481600834, 1.08964596607244, 
1.20630719708568, 1.34382587758861, 1.46128278798956, 1.59936153416788, 
1.68352966297731, 1.78940871644707, 2.17325620779303, 2.32171388099973, 
2.49752109350884, 2.57130991397796, 2.68019961742924, 2.81373363068119, 
3.12568790968636, 3.2559207639547, 3.32614231903036, 3.43501009186589, 
3.66697204643782, 3.75944221250401, 3.87518960476143, 3.98816098787005, 
4.12564790942336, 4.47361508632088, 4.66173225584577, 4.87187647554418, 
5.06499864973269, 5.26139485499848, 5.42077894932731, 5.70971751250438, 
6.08663753750477, 6.3544029256183, 6.6099290032563, 6.86699820314081, 
7.60406134878737, 8.02453396711809, 8.46290889731311, 8.82551281645418, 
10.4087012189772, 11.5894414578226, 13.2373523390222, 13.5038153563633, 
-12.8877947524831, -12.5961340486959, -11.3210853809037, -10.2570925911286, 
-8.47030492676585, -8.10018637873416, -7.67303749757961, -7.28202887686486, 
-6.60931905266524, -6.44634841642492, -6.21582362929168, -5.93115698481963, 
-5.5215432443443, -5.19600239869575, -5.04972087076752, -4.87543206990054, 
-4.69028336184037, -4.46914150055587, -4.33123842894087, -3.99361363184664, 
-3.833076928421, -3.77408485453713, -3.6640925546724, -3.59372660759739, 
-3.32461379011727, -3.21096198541142, -3.13898393694403, -3.00388455382712, 
-2.72134261347931, -2.57066623804085, -2.49408041291093, -2.41796583370138, 
-2.26369776447253, -2.07966723692233, -1.64375650300888, -1.54786821816088, 
-1.46043531083332, -1.33166687876378, -1.21629813646533, -1.09475471308712, 
-0.990331188483095, -0.880770453063485, -0.831512873094893, -0.711368103958197, 
-0.64608803628934, -0.576583643383317, -0.389788923647592, -0.219325408944189, 
-0.101244293663156, 0, 0.101244293663156, 0.219325408944189, 
0.389788923647592, 0.576583643383317, 0.64608803628934, 0.711368103958197, 
0.831512873094893, 0.880770453063485, 0.990331188483095, 1.09475471308712, 
1.21629813646533, 1.33166687876378, 1.46043531083332, 1.54786821816088, 
1.64375650300888, 2.07966723692233, 2.26369776447253, 2.41796583370138, 
2.49408041291093, 2.57066623804085, 2.72134261347931, 3.00388455382712, 
3.13898393694403, 3.21096198541142, 3.32461379011727, 3.59372660759739, 
3.6640925546724, 3.77408485453713, 3.833076928421, 3.99361363184664, 
4.33123842894087, 4.46914150055587, 4.69028336184037, 4.87543206990054, 
5.04972087076752, 5.19600239869575, 5.5215432443443, 5.93115698481963, 
6.21582362929168, 6.44634841642492, 6.60931905266524, 7.28202887686486, 
7.67303749757961, 8.10018637873416, 8.47030492676585, 10.2570925911286, 
11.3210853809037, 12.5961340486959, 12.8877947524831, -12.6000848203634, 
-12.2966556390103, -11.1957507602953, -10.1862843945321, -8.30440651819497, 
-7.93147284818737, -7.50817793772083, -7.13162491301438, -6.48897104737938, 
-6.36994876479492, -6.15110072929745, -5.85854042138457, -5.43365721329602, 
-5.09102141962306, -4.95085939235108, -4.78689576531572, -4.60547103236952, 
-4.37919276705198, -4.26474198682156, -3.93194755639431, -3.77843705689023, 
-3.70907277842741, -3.61955988253518, -3.55951762156004, -3.27305364378077, 
-3.15716747633446, -3.08436906473098, -2.94699678899349, -2.67819176248474, 
-2.51950911610342, -2.45801068672049, -2.38080987129559, -2.23660157184075, 
-2.03595688651075, -1.58836441712333, -1.47187389747016, -1.39555037998287, 
-1.27113029247092, -1.15673682064109, -1.0426545765059, -0.943946623196274, 
-0.835837575946843, -0.805837349555374, -0.689648730659341, -0.648094429117022, 
-0.584092303333525, -0.394149224677363, -0.222824659020402, -0.0906541511144734, 
0, 0.0906541511144734, 0.222824659020402, 0.394149224677363, 
0.584092303333525, 0.648094429117022, 0.689648730659341, 0.805837349555374, 
0.835837575946843, 0.943946623196274, 1.0426545765059, 1.15673682064109, 
1.27113029247092, 1.39555037998287, 1.47187389747016, 1.58836441712333, 
2.03595688651075, 2.23660157184075, 2.38080987129559, 2.45801068672049, 
2.51950911610342, 2.67819176248474, 2.94699678899349, 3.08436906473098, 
3.15716747633446, 3.27305364378077, 3.55951762156004, 3.61955988253518, 
3.70907277842741, 3.77843705689023, 3.93194755639431, 4.26474198682156, 
4.37919276705198, 4.60547103236952, 4.78689576531572, 4.95085939235108, 
5.09102141962306, 5.43365721329602, 5.85854042138457, 6.15110072929745, 
6.36994876479492, 6.48897104737938, 7.13162491301438, 7.50817793772083, 
7.93147284818737, 8.30440651819497, 10.1862843945321, 11.1957507602953, 
12.2966556390103, 12.6000848203634, -12.7233949898779, -12.425009683628, 
-11.2494681735225, -10.2166322197219, -8.3755092456272, -8.00338523998922, 
-7.57923229725886, -7.19608684570266, -6.5405512372713, -6.40269304276938, 
-6.17884044516668, -5.8896632980985, -5.47132446137006, -5.13601542532135, 
-4.9932306291456, -4.82484171541241, -4.64182091659811, -4.41774407285591, 
-4.29324182862204, -3.95837714178017, -3.80090594237893, -3.73788575810611, 
-3.6386462286676, -3.57417931862452, -3.29515190899568, -3.18022337150066, 
-3.10777656095811, -2.97137842876953, -2.69668587115743, -2.54143464829308, 
-2.47346988209172, -2.39673461879726, -2.24821478269518, -2.05469079214647, 
-1.61210502089736, -1.50444445385474, -1.42335954097761, -1.29707578786137, 
-1.18226432293022, -1.06498427720905, -0.963826675880699, -0.85422851115692, 
-0.817708608597364, -0.698957479868998, -0.647234505242058, -0.580874151897233, 
-0.392280434624987, -0.221324908501217, -0.0951930012794266, 
0, 0.0951930012794266, 0.221324908501217, 0.392280434624987, 
0.580874151897233, 0.647234505242058, 0.698957479868998, 0.817708608597364, 
0.85422851115692, 0.963826675880699, 1.06498427720905, 1.18226432293022, 
1.29707578786137, 1.42335954097761, 1.50444445385474, 1.61210502089736, 
2.05469079214647, 2.24821478269518, 2.39673461879726, 2.47346988209172, 
2.54143464829308, 2.69668587115743, 2.97137842876953, 3.10777656095811, 
3.18022337150066, 3.29515190899568, 3.57417931862452, 3.6386462286676, 
3.73788575810611, 3.80090594237893, 3.95837714178017, 4.29324182862204, 
4.41774407285591, 4.64182091659811, 4.82484171541241, 4.9932306291456, 
5.13601542532135, 5.47132446137006, 5.8896632980985, 6.17884044516668, 
6.40269304276938, 6.5405512372713, 7.19608684570266, 7.57923229725886, 
8.00338523998922, 8.3755092456272, 10.2166322197219, 11.2494681735225, 
12.425009683628, 12.7233949898779, -12.9701665831908, -12.6818752140478, 
-11.3569688906404, -10.2773650952434, -8.51780191626772, -8.14868819459235, 
-7.72003821070641, -7.32508978114711, -6.64377488616525, -6.46822176338875, 
-6.23435390289731, -5.95194722735932, -5.54670516078474, -5.22605862710606, 
-5.07802507599128, -4.90078016073291, -4.71456527242172, -4.49489397213016, 
-4.35027647059818, -4.01126873151645, -3.85381415345849, -3.78760418054142, 
-3.67684233255883, -3.6035206970325, -3.33937554552141, -3.22636344257365, 
-3.15462026543263, -3.02017161524238, -2.73369677368098, -2.58531260689116, 
-2.50440723533775, -2.42860364735808, -2.27145544935968, -2.09218158273497, 
-1.66032132882236, -1.56891953844307, -1.47901197414181, -1.34899860381407, 
-1.23335063996306, -1.10967106859385, -1.00361116644947, -0.894069184830091, 
-0.838429443534018, -0.717586396553344, -0.645513602695347, -0.574433901587114, 
-0.388540562231589, -0.218323567844169, -0.104276269037671, 0, 
0.104276269037671, 0.218323567844169, 0.388540562231589, 0.574433901587114, 
0.645513602695347, 0.717586396553344, 0.838429443534018, 0.894069184830091, 
1.00361116644947, 1.10967106859385, 1.23335063996306, 1.34899860381407, 
1.47901197414181, 1.56891953844307, 1.66032132882236, 2.09218158273497, 
2.27145544935968, 2.42860364735808, 2.50440723533775, 2.58531260689116, 
2.73369677368098, 3.02017161524238, 3.15462026543263, 3.22636344257365, 
3.33937554552141, 3.6035206970325, 3.67684233255883, 3.78760418054142, 
3.85381415345849, 4.01126873151645, 4.35027647059818, 4.49489397213016, 
4.71456527242172, 4.90078016073291, 5.07802507599128, 5.22605862710606, 
5.54670516078474, 5.95194722735932, 6.23435390289731, 6.46822176338875, 
6.64377488616525, 7.32508978114711, 7.72003821070641, 8.14868819459235, 
8.51780191626772, 10.2773650952434, 11.3569688906404, 12.6818752140478, 
12.9701665831908), .Dim = c(99L, 11L))
```

Each column is a function for me that I want to integrate, and put the values in my `integr` matrix:

```
 integr=matrix(0,11)

 for (t in 1:11){
     integrating = approxfun(thau,func[,t],rule=2)
     integr[t,1]=integrate(integrating, lower = 0.01, upper = 0.5,subdivisions = 1000)$value
}
```

I have this error message:

```
Error in integrate(integrating, lower = 0.01, upper = 0.5, subdivisions = 1000) : 
  extremely bad integrand behaviour
```

How do I get around this problem and continue to use the function `integrate` in R. Will I need to do some non-linear approach? If so, how can I do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is your function differenetiable? If not than the `integrate` method of numeric integration will not work.

Comment: Yes. I can integrate some columns, but not all the columns.

Comment: Which column is having problems?

Comment: The 5th, for example. But this is a example of matrix. My real matrix has more than 300 columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it is very interesting to see quite a few numerical integration question regarding quantile function in the last 10 days or so. For example:

- [Building a function by defining X and Y and then Integrating in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40273920/4891738)
- [Standard Normal Quantile Function Integration in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40295142/4891738)
- [Understanding and implementing numerical integration with a quantile function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40306378/4891738)

Note how this question is similar to the first one. Although you did not mention what `thau` is, I believe it is `thau <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)`. Let's have sketch your `func` matrix against `thau`:

```
matplot(thau, func, type = "l")
```

[image]

Also, let's verify that all columns of `func` are monotonically increasing:

```
all(diff(func) > 0)
# [1] TRUE
```

Basically, your question is using the answer I provided in the 1st linked question (the justification of `rule = 2` is given in the 3rd linked question, though). But thanks to your question; I now realize there are some potential numerical flaw behind.

---

It is sophisticated for me to understand the mathematics behind Adaptive Quadrature in a limited time as I am not an expert in the field. But it is rather surprising to me that it would fail sometime on such a trivial task. 
As I mentioned in the 2nd linked question, we can even use trapezoidal rule.

When I test `integrate`, it is the 1st column of `func` rather than the 5th as you reported that fails.

```
## get interpolation function for all columns in a list
flst <- lapply(1:ncol(func), function (i) approxfun(thau, func[,i], rule = 2))

## all OK excluding the 1st column
sapply(flst[-1], function (fun) integrate(fun, 0.01, 0.5)$value)
# [1] -2.010421 -2.088981 -2.114083 -2.000653 -2.015932 -1.986130 -1.912076
# [8] -1.877459 -1.892291 -1.921983

## the 1st one fails
integrate(flst[[1]], 0.01, 0.5)
#  extremely bad integrand behaviour
```

As said earlier, I believe this failure artificial due to the problem's simple nature. In fact, let's consider

```
integrate(flst[[1]], 0.01 + .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.25, 0.5)
# -2.13653 with absolute error < 8.7e-05

integrate(flst[[1]], 0, 0.5)
# -2.286034 with absolute error < 0.00027
```

They all work.

---

As far as I can explore, the `integrate` function is using two Fortran subroutines:

- [`dqags`](http://netlib.sandia.gov/quadpack/dqags.f) for definite integral, capable to deal with end-points singularity;
- [`dqagi`](http://netlib.sandia.gov/quadpack/dqagi.f) for indefinite integral.

R documentation for `integrate` does not explain much on the error handling of those routines, but the Fortran page does a little. Unfortunately, it is still not extremely clear what the "bad behaviour" is. But it is clear enough to see that regardless what error code is, those Fortran subroutines will always return integration result.

A look at the source code of `integrate` verifies this. Integration result is stored in variable `wk`, then a `swtich` statement is used to interpret the integer error code stored in `wk$ierr`:

```
res$message <- switch(wk$ierr + 1L, "OK", "maximum number of subdivisions reached", 
    "roundoff error was detected", "extremely bad integrand behaviour", 
    "roundoff error is detected in the extrapolation table", 
    "the integral is probably divergent", "the input is invalid")
if (wk$ierr == 6L || (wk$ierr > 0L && stop.on.error)) 
    stop(res$message)
```

The `if` statement following this `switch` decides whether we want to ignore any error. **Note there is an `stop.on.error` argument in `integrate`; if we set it `FALSE` instead of the default `TRUE`, `integrate` will always work.** Therefore, let's do

```
z <- integrate(flst[[1]], 0.01, 0.5, stop.on.error = FALSE)

str(z)
# $ value       : num -2.14
# $ abs.error   : num 0.000446
# $ subdivisions: int 69
# $ message     : chr "extremely bad integrand behaviour"
# $ call        : language integrate(f = flst[[1]], lower = 0.01, upper = 0.5, stop.on.error = FALSE)
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "integrate"

z$value
# [1] -2.138348
```

This is all I can do at the moment. I believe there will be an opportunity for me to read around Adaptive Quadrature in the near future.

Comment: Thanks! Amazing your answer! I will check the questions that you suggested.